# Exporting a function from p5.js with Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, p5.js

First, I have a p5.js script:

```
//canvas.js
var p5 = require('p5')

module.exports = new p5(function () {
  this.setup = function setup () {
    this.createCanvas(700, 400)
    this.background(205)
    this.loadImage('/uploads/uploaded_image', function (img) {
      image(img, 0, 0)
    })
    this.updatePixels()
  }
  this.clearCanvas = function redraw () {
    this.background('black')
  }
```

Everything is in a new p5 object so that it would bundle with browserify because p5, as I understand runs in the global namespace. This worked fine but I needed a button that would turn the whole canvas black so I added a new function clearCanvas that redraws the canvas all in black. I added the module.exports part so that I could require in the p5 object and use this new function in another script. Then I added a button in my jade file:

```
    button(type='button', id='clear').
            Click to clear
```

And then I created a handler that would require in the p5 exported object and use the clearCanvas function onClick:

```
var canvas = require('./canvas.js')

document.getElementById('clear').onclick = function () {
  canvas.clearCanvas()
}
```

The result is two errors in the console:

bundle.js:34633 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

bundle.js:14197 p5 had problems creating the global function "clear", possibly because your code is already using that name as a variable. You may want to rename your variable to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered here:

[Exporting p5.js function with Browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37539141/exporting-p5-js-function-with-browserify)

p5.js runs in the global object and to export a function that's not built-in to p5 you must run p5 in instance mode. This also allows you to run multiple instances of p5.